# answerCallbackQuery telegram api

Tags: laravel, telegram

I use this extention for telegram bot api [irazasyed](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk). When I click on inlineKeyboard there is sign of awainting [example](http://joxi.ru/8An9DjpFqPwzP2). I add answerCallbackQuery method for fix that

```
$id = $request['callback_query']['id'];
$keyboard = new KeyboardController();
$keyboard->selectLanguage($chatid, $bot_name);
try{

            $message = new SendMessageController();
            $message->sendMessage($chatid,$id,$bot_name);
            $telegram = new Api();
            $telegram->answerCallbackQuery([
                'callback_query_id' => $id,
            ]);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $message = new SendMessageController();
            $message->sendMessage($chatid,$e->getMessage(),$bot_name);
        }
```

I get in message `$id`(from `try`) but from block `catch` I get error `Bad Request: QUERYIDINVALID`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue mostly happens, if you answer the request too late.

E.g. you tap the inline button on 12:00:00 in the Telegram app and your bot calls answerCallbackQuery on 12:00:16, then the callback_query_id will be invalidated by that time. You got about 15 seconds until you get the "QUERYID_INVALID" error.

Also mind the time the request is "travelling" from the Telegram servers to your server **and back**. Those 15 seconds are counting when the message leaves Telegram servers and stops counting, when it arrives back there.

Comment: blocl `catch` return `Bad Request: QUERYIDINVALID` after 1-2 seconds after button click

Comment: Then probably the `$id` is an invalid one. Have you tried printing it? Maybe the callback query gets answered by another telegram bot instance?

Comment: `$id = $request['callback_query']['id'];
elseif ($text == 'Select language')
{
try{
$telegram = new Api();
$telegram->answerCallbackQuery([
'callback_query_id' => $id
]);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$message = new SendMessageController();
$message->sendMessage($chatid,$id . '/ ' .$text . '/'.$e->getMessage(),$bot_name);
}`  I got this `1495377079129429867/ Select language/Bad Request: QUERYIDINVALID`

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger on your code? You could get detailled information where and when the code "crashes".

I am pretty sure it's either that you are 1) **too late**, 2) the query is **already answered** or maybe 3) the `$id` is **not a string**, but an int? I am not sure if the type is automatically assigned when passing to `answerCallbackQuery`.

Comment: `gettype($id)` return string. message about invalid id comes in less than a second after button click(not too late). if query was already answered there are no animation on button and message `bot is not responding`.